# How to create a Gorm type that is both a slice and serializable to jsonb

Tags: go, jsonb, go-gorm

I have a field on a Gorm model that needs to be saved to a Postgres DB as `jsonb`. However, in memory I'd like to be able to treat the field like an ordinary slice to index into it and use its fields.

I've attempted to implement a `JSONSlice` type that is an alias for a slice of interfaces that implement JSON marshal and unmarshal methods. However, when I attempt to actually use the type I'm hitting errors during JSON decoding at runtime.

The code is:

```golang
package models

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
)

type jsonSliceElement interface {type Foo struct {
  ID int64 `json:"id"`
}

func (f *Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  type Alias Foo
  return json.Marshal((*Alias)(f))
}

func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  type Alias Foo
  aux := (*Alias)(f)
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
}

type JSONSlice []jsonSliceElement

func (js JSONSlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if js == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    ba, err := js.MarshalJSON()
    return string(ba), err
}

func (js *JSONSlice) Scan(val interface{}) error {
    var ba []byte
    switch v := val.(type) {
    case []byte:
        ba = v
    case string:
        ba = []byte(v)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to unmarshal JSONB value: %+v", val)
    }

    t := []jsonSliceElement{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(ba, &t)
    *js = JSONSlice(t)

    return err
}

func (js JSONSlice) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if js == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    t := ([]jsonSliceElement)(js)

    return json.Marshal(t)
}

func (js *JSONSlice) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    t := []jsonSliceElement{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    *js = JSONSlice(t)

    return err
}

func (m JSONSlice) GormDataType() string {
    return "jsonslice"
}

func (JSONSlice) GormDBDataType(db *gorm.DB, field *schema.Field) string {
    switch db.Dialector.Name() {
    case "sqlite":
        return "JSON"
    case "mysql":
        return "JSON"
    case "postgres":
        return "JSONB"
    }
    return ""
}

type Foo struct {
  ID int64 `json:"id"`
}

func (f *Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  type Alias Foo
  return json.Marshal((*Alias)(f))
}

func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  type Alias Foo
  aux := (*Alias)(f)
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

I'm building up a `JSONSlice{}` of `Foo` instances, but am seeing the following error:

```
unable to decode: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Bar.foos of type models.jsonSliceElement (type: wrapError, retryable: true): unable to decode
```

It seems like perhaps I'm serializing my `Foo` types to JSON incorrectly? Or is there a better way to achieve the goal of a type that works like a slice in code, but serializes to the DB as JSONB with Gorm? Thanks!

Comment: how about using json. RawMessage or []byte as the data type to keep things simple

Comment: @Rengas I need to be able to treat the data in memory as a slice of structs. Then I need that data to serialize to the DB as jsonb

Comment: @Michael please add the usage example how you are using the implementation in you code.